# Different space quotas for different Windows users

Tags: windows-7, quota

On Windows 7, is it possible to have set different disk space quotas for different users? How?

For example I'd like to limit my kids' disk usage to ~50 GB each, my roommate's to 100 GB, and so on.

Comment: What have you researched and/or tried so far?

Comment: LMGTFY http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/76002-disk-quota-set-space-limits-users.html

Comment: What edition of Windows are you running?  Home/Pro/Enterprise/Ultimate?  I know I can easily do this on Enterprise/Ultimate.  Never tried on Home.

Comment: @Uninspired, thanks. I did search before posting but did not turn up that information; guess I used sub-optimal phrases.

Answer (score 2):

You can [partition the hard drive](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309170.aspx) in the computer and then dictate access to the different drives with [group policies](http://www.ehow.com/how_8088979_restrict-hard-drives-windows-7.html). Unfortunately parental controls don't give the option of restricting different drives.

This also provides the benefit of knowing exactly where they are putting their files(in their lettered drive, possibly named after them) and lets you revoke their access to the windows system files which kids love to play around in.

Answer (score 2):

Courtesy of @Uninspired and the [Sevenforums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/76002-disk-quota-set-space-limits-users.html), the answer is to dig past the first level of Quota dialog interface and use the *[Quota Entries]* button.

[image: Quota and Quota Entries dialog]